# WPF: Binding DataGrid to collection programmatically

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, user-controls, itemssource

I already spent hours on this, and similar topics did not help. :(

I've got an object of type "Chart" which contains a List "LineItems".
I want to bind LineItems programmatically to a DataGrid in an UserControl.

Usercontrol XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="myData" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
```

Usercontrol Code behind:

```
    public void SetItemSource(ChartingBase.Chart chart)
    {
        //DataGrid.ItemsSource = chart.LineItems; // working!

        // this is not working:
        this.DataContext = chart;
        Binding b = new Binding( "LineItems" );
        b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        b.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        myData.SetBinding( DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, b );
    }
```

Setting just the ItemsSource works. Creating the binding manually does not work and I have no clue what else I could try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(myData, DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("LineItems") { Source = chart });
```

Answer (score -1):

In WPF, it is customary to put your data into an `ObservableCollection<T>` collection and data bind that to the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property. Then you can fill or manipulate the collection in code and the UI will update automatically. Try this:

```
<DataGrid Name="myData" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
```

...

```
public void SetItemSource(ChartingBase.Chart chart)
{
    this.DataContext = chart;
    Items = new ObservableCollection<YourDataType>();
    foreach (SomeDataType dataType in chart.SomeCollection)
    {
        Items.Add(new YourDataType(dataType.SomeProperty, ...));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.
ObservableCollection - okay.

But: if Items is a collection inside my Usercontrol, I have to set the DataContext to 'Self', right?
And I can't use copies of my objects.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means and I don't know where your data is coming from... it was just an example. Fill your collection anyway you want.